# Firebase Node API v9 access to functions.config() and functions.logger()?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

After changing the initialization code of my Firebase functions to the v9 API as described here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#web-version-9_2), the "functions" object no longer has config() or logger(). How do I access functions.config() and functions.logger() using the new API? I've looked through the library source, including the "compat" libraries, and looked for all the documentation I can find, but with no luck. Is this even possible, or has Google just not gotten around to it yet?

Comment: Can you confirm if you have installed this SDK in a Cloud function or client app? The new Modular SDK is for client side usage not for creating Cloud functions.

Comment: Yes, I have since come to understand that "firebase-functions" and "firebase/functions" are different products for different purposes, though I am using them both (I am writing cloud functions and test code for them that runs on client side). It would be difficult to imagine how to make this more badly documented and difficult to understand for a typical programmer--or even an experienced one like me.

Comment: I posted an answer for the same to clarify for future visitors as well :D

Comment: Your answer is basically "you can't do that client-side", which, while true, isn't the most helpful. Since I'm writing test code for the cloud functions, I need to know what environment they are being run under. My current method (which you might mention in your answer) is to simply load the ".runtimeconfig.json" file which was created from "firebase functions:config:get". It appears that another approach is to use the Google Cloud Deployment Manager API? I didn't try that, so I can't verify.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? Originally question sounded more like a confusion in those 2 SDKs. You can get runtime config in a Cloud function using `firebase-functions` pkg only.

Comment: Yes, I got that. My cloud functions are indeed using firebase-functions package to access runtime config. Now I'm trying to write client-side test functions using "firebase/functions", but those functions need to know the same config info in order to do the test. It seems like a reasonable thing for that library to provide access--which I know is possible because the "firebase functions:config:get" CLI does it. But apparently it does not, so I either have to investigate how the CLI does it (apparently with the Google Cloud Deployment Manager API), or just keep a local copy of the config.

Answer (score 0):

The new Firebase Modular SDK (from `npm i firebase`) is meant for client and not to create Cloud Functions (which is `npm i firebase-functions`). The `logger()` and `config()` methods are available in `firebase-functions` SDK. You can then use the modular SDK to *call* the functions from your web app.

```js
/* Usage on client side */
// V8
var addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage');

// V9
const addMessage = httpsCallable(functions, 'addMessage');
```

Answer (score 0):

From your additional comments, it was clear that you want to obtain the environment variables and use them when you run Firebase Functions from the client side with the Modular SDK. One option to avoid locally storing the variables is to use the [Runtime Configuration API](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/reference/rest/) to expose and retrieve the configuration variables from your project. This is the API used by the CLI command firebase `functions:config:get` according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#retrieve_current_environment_configuration):

> This functionality is based on the Google Cloud Runtime Configuration API.

The Runtime Configuration API is also available as a [Node.js](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/44.0.0/runtimeconfig/classes/Runtimeconfig.html) package. Using the REST API, there are endpoints, such as `projects.configs.get`, which returns runtime configuration data.

For logging, you can use the Node.js [logging client library](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) to write log entries and retrieve logs.